# Overloading the += operator in a class for a Node member

Tags: c++, operators, overloading, nodes

I'm trying to overload the += operator in my program. It consists of a polynomial class that includes an int degree (the highest degree of the polynomial) and a Node* Poly (a pointer to a node)

```
struct Node{ int coefficient;
             Node* next; };
```

that is my Node struct, I am overloading in the Polynomial class though.

```
  Polynomial& Polynomial::operator +=(const Polynomial& rP){
    Polynomial copyRP(rP);
    poly->coefficient = poly->coefficient + copyRP.poly->coefficient;
    poly = poly->next; //if I take this and
    copyRP.poly = copyRP.poly->next; //this away, it runs fine
    //with it however the program compiles but doesnt work 
    return *this;
  }
```

The node contains the list of the coefficients backwards, if that matters.  For example 3x^2+2x+5 is stored in the node as 5->2->3 and has a degree of 2.

Comment: And what's the definition of the Polynomial class? How does it "not work"? Why do you need the lines without which you say it works fine? Why would `operator+=` make a copy of anything?

Comment: I made a copy because `rP.poly = rP.poly->next` would say that the lvalue cannot be modified, and it doesnt work if i keep `poly = poly->next` and `copyRP.poly = copyRP.poly->next`, and i forgot to put the `while(poly != NULL)` to add thru the whole node, but i have it in my program

Comment: pretty much, if i have two polynomials, one is 3x^2+2x+2 and 2x^2+3x+4, i want to return 5x^2+5x+6, the addition of those two polynomials, but whenever i try to `return *this`, it doesnt let me, however if i make a copy of `this`, it lets me return the copy, i dont get it!!!

Comment: oo and `class Polynomial{private: int degree; Node* poly};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
struct polynomial {
    std::vector< int > coeffs;
    std::size_t degree() const { return coeffs.size(); }
};

polynomial &polynomial::operator+= ( polynomial &lhs, polynomial const &rhs ) {
    if ( lhs.degree() < rhs.degree() ) lhs.coeffs.resize( rhs.degree() );
    for ( std::size_t k = 0; k != rhs.degree(); ++ k ) {
        lhs.coeffs[ k ] += rhs.coeffs[ k ];
    }
    return lhs;
}
```

No linked lists, no manual memory management, you can easily change it to another numeric type.

Comment: i wish i could!!! i'm taking a c++ class, and this is part of a hw, and the point of the hw is to have a node like i did, i can't change that =(

Comment: @user1828659 Ah, you didn't mention that. Please note that it's a **very** bad idea to write a linked list when you could use the standard library. As you've observed, that leads to unstable programs. Having a project like that indicates that your class is giving you bad, useless advice.

Comment: I found out what to do! I just had to do `Node* p = poly` and `Node* r = rP.poly` and from there it works, thanks for your help anyways! And it's not always a bad idea to use linked lists, they're useful in their own ways.

Comment: @user1828659 You don't need to *write* a linked list to *use* a linked list. `std::list` is the solution in that case, and you can simply replace `vector` in this code with `list` to achieve that. Such is the power of a leveraging a library. The bad advice has nothing to do with the particular data structure, the bad advice is to write any data structure at all when a library is available. You can go through your entire career without implementing any data structure at all, and those you do need to implement (due to higher complexity), often require the use of a library to get right.

Comment: I see, i really appreciate your input! I didn't know that `list` was something that i could use, and I guess what my professor is doing is showing us every way to do things, although i think that for programming, showing the best way to do something would be more efficient. Anyways, i really do appreciate all the input! Thanks again for trying to help, I'll definitely be looking into this!